# Replace nulls with the last non-null value using Redshift

Tags: null, amazon-redshift, fill

I have a table called quantities:

```
+----------+----------+
| date     | quantity |
+----------+----------+
| 30/11/17 | 90       |
+----------+----------+
| 01/12/17 |          |
+----------+----------+
| 02/12/17 |          |
+----------+----------+
| 03/12/17 | 1622     |
+----------+----------+
| 04/12/17 |          |
+----------+----------+
| 05/12/17 | 9092     |
+----------+----------+
| 06/12/17 |          |
+----------+----------+
| 07/12/17 |          |
+----------+----------+
| 08/12/17 | 2132     |
+----------+----------+
| 09/12/17 |          |
+----------+----------+
| 10/12/17 | 2889     |
+----------+----------+
```

And I want to select it so that I can fill in the blanks with the previous non-null value:

```
+----------+----------+
| date     | quantity |
+----------+----------+
| 30/11/17 | 90       |
+----------+----------+
| 01/12/17 | 90       |
+----------+----------+
| 02/12/17 | 90       |
+----------+----------+
| 03/12/17 | 1622     |
+----------+----------+
| 04/12/17 | 1622     |
+----------+----------+
| 05/12/17 | 9092     |
+----------+----------+
| 06/12/17 | 9092     |
+----------+----------+
| 07/12/17 | 9092     |
+----------+----------+
| 08/12/17 | 2132     |
+----------+----------+
| 09/12/17 | 2132     |
+----------+----------+
| 10/12/17 | 2889     |
+----------+----------+
```

I am using PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.1499

How could I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

something like 
`last_value(quantity ignore nulls) over (order by date rows unbounded preceding)`

it's a window function that returns the last value in the specified window

Comment: working as expected, it's been very helpful. thank you

Answer (score -1):

You may use something on the lines of:

```
select date,(select t.quantity from [tablename] t where t.quantity is not null and t.date <= t1.date
order by t.date desc limit 1) from [tablename] t1;
```

`t.quantity is not null`: It makes sure you don't get null values in result set.

`t.date <= t1.date`: It ensures the last known value is picked.